# Running Program on Server

Tags: python, server

I want to build a system where users can upload their own Python code. The code will then be run and marked for correctness. The result should be outputted to the user.

I have very limited knowledge of servers and can't find the right place to start. What would be the easiest way to approach this problem and where should I start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will give you some pointers.

You should consider creating a docker image and running the code in that. This way the program will not have access to the server machine you are hosting it on. You will need to write the code to a file and copy it over to docker using Dockerfile.

As far as checking the answers look into testing frameworks to assert the output matches what you expect.

I recommend taking a free online course or tutorial about Docker and having a basic understanding of Linux commands.